# How to configure logging for libreoffice standard installation on RedHat

Tags: logging, redhat, rpm, configure, libreoffice

I have a standard libreoffice installation installed by rpm on a RedHat EL6 system.

- Is it possible to configure the logging for this libreoffice installation (lower the level-treshold, set the output-logfile, ...) - and if yes: how would I do that?